# How do I get Tiles 2 to work with a Spring MVC 3 web app?

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

Is there some easy to follow tutorial for a Spring MVC newbie to add Tiles 2 to a very simple application?  Heck, I don't really care if it's Tiles 2.  I just can't stand copying the same JSP over and over.

I come from the Rails world where partials are dirt simple.

I basically just need a main.jsp file that contains sections that I can replace from other JSP's.

< rant >
Every tutorial I find lists what seems like hundreds of lines of XML and assumes I know what viewResolvers, ContextLoadListeners and JohnsonRods are.  I realize I have a lot to learn.  I'm proud that after only 3 days I got clean urls and annotated controllers working.  But being a C# and Ruby developer, I'm finding Java web programming painful.  (btw, my day time job is moving me to Java that's why I must suffer the pain..lol)
< /rant >

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Spring is not a small plugin.  There is alot to learn.  Read the Spring 3 reference (every word).  Then, probabaly, read it again.  Also, there are more than 1 ways to skin a spring project.  The reference shows some (often one) ways to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this.  I was told to use Struts 1 instead...  :-/

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you should try [Spring Roo,](http://www.springsource.org/roo).  The webapp generated by it uses Tiles2.

You could also see if [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-tiles-plugin-tutorial-example-eclipse.html) helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial but I already found that one.  Followed it to the letter and it didn't work.  I have the simplest Spring MVC app I can think of and it still didn't work.  This is ultimately my problem.  Roo looked interesting but the rule around here is that if a contractor doesn't understand it we don't use it.  Yeah.

Comment: Use roo to create a tiles project.  Once this is done, you will have an example of a working tiles project to use as a reference.